# dhcp ip discovered but not append to interface eth0 or wlan0

Tags: dynamic, interface, ip, wifi

We are using the Linux with kernel 3.8.17 on Intel Galileo 2 board . we are using Ethernet (eth0) and wireless WiFi(wlan0) interface on same board.
We are successfully discover the dynamic IP from server using the udhcpc utility but obtained IP does not automatically  appended to the interface like WiFi (wlan0)or Ethernet(eth0).

Example:

Command

```
   udhcpc -i wlan0
```

Response

```
Discovery IP..

Discovery IP..

Discover IP 192.168.60.54
```

After this we check below command

```
 Ifconfig wlan0
```

But wlan0 does not get IP.

So please help us to solve the above problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think You did not configure Wi-Fi to managed mode.
Look at [Intel Galileo Meets Wireless](http://www.malinov.com/Home/sergey-s-blog/intelgalileo-addingwifi)